# SQL date cannot be converted to Lang.string

Tags: java, mysql, date

This void function tests the QCManual Results table. When reaching:

**String date = (String) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.RUNDATE_INDEX);**

Throws Error

```
public static void checkManualResult(QCManualResultsTableModel qcModel, int row)
    {
        ArrayList<QcResultViolation> violations;
        RuleEvaluator evaluator = null;
        MultiMap<QcRules, QcSteps> ruleMap = new MultiMap<>();
        if (qcModel.getRowCount() > 0)
        {
           //try {
            Integer resultInstId = (Integer) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.INSTID_INDEX);
            Integer qcLotId = (Integer) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.LOTID_INDEX);
            Integer resultLevel = (Integer) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.LEVEL_INDEX);
            Integer testNumber = (Integer) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.TESTNUM_INDEX);
            Double result = (Double) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.RESULT_INDEX);
            String date = (String) qcModel.getValueAt(row, QCManualResultsTableModel.QCManualResult.RUNDATE_INDEX);
            evaluator = new RuleEvaluator(resultInstId);
            ruleMap = getRules(resultInstId, resultLevel, qcLotId); 
            if (ruleMap.size() > 0 && result != null)
            {
                evaluator.SetRuleMap(ruleMap);
                violations = evaluator.CheckResult(testNumber, resultLevel, qcLotId, resultInstId, new BigDecimal(result), date);
            }
```

Stack Trace Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.css.QCApproval.QCUtil.checkManualResult(QCUtil.java:88)
    at org.css.QCTables.QCManualResultsTableModel.setValueAt(QCManualResultsTableModel.java:418)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2741)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable.setValueAt(JXTable.java:1473)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(JTable.java:4723)
    at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(AbstractCellEditor.java:141)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:368)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(DefaultCellEditor.java:233)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.table.NumberEditorExt.stopCellEditing(NumberEditorExt.java:129)
    at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.actionPerformed(DefaultCellEditor.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField$CommitAction.actionPerformed(JFormattedTextField.java:1124)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1662)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6293)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1887)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4742)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` to format your date value into a String, according to your preferred formatting.

Comment: @TheImpaler No, under no circumstances use `SimpleDateFormat` for anything. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). See the answer.

Comment: @TheImpaler As the answer shows, getting a modern date-time object is easy in this case. If you had had an old-fashioned `java.sql.Date` object as in the question, convert and be happy: `yourJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a string object to be a date-time object. The types are unrelated.

You can ask a date-time object to *generate* text.

Never use the terribly flawed legacy date-time types such as `java.sql.Date`. Use only *java.time* classes.

To retrieve a value from a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `DATE`, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

To generate text in other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` classes. These have been covered extensively, so search to learn more.